# KCL stops processing data after throwing error Cancelling subscription, and restarting

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-kcl

KCL

**ShardConsumerSubscriber:131 - shardId-000000000000: Last request was dispatched at 2020-04-28T12:57:25.166Z, but no response as of 2020-04-28T12:58:00.435Z (PT35.269S).  Cancelling subscription, and restarting."**
 But never restarts application and no data is processed after that.
Maven dependency used

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.kinesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And the Kinesis configuration

```
KinesisAsyncClient kinesisClient = KinesisAsyncClient.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(new MyCredentialProvider(configVals)).region(region).build();
InitialPositionInStreamExtended initialPositionInStreamExtended = InitialPositionInStreamExtended
        .newInitialPosition(InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON);
RetrievalConfig retrievalConfig = configsBuilder.retrievalConfig()
        .retrievalSpecificConfig(new PollingConfig(configVals.getStreamName(), kinesisClient)
                .idleTimeBetweenReadsInMillis(10000).maxRecords(50).kinesisRequestTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(100)));
retrievalConfig.initialPositionInStreamExtended(initialPositionInStreamExtended);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's stated in issue [KCL 2.0 stops consuming from some shards #463](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/issues/463), the main reason can be the fact that the processor is not able to process the input in `35 seconds`. This value is hardcoded in `ShardConsumer` in `MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_REQUEST_RESPONSE` variable and is increased to `1 minute` in later versions (I'm using kcl version `2.2.10` and it's 60 seconds already).

I've also experienced this issue and additionally had to override kinesis client http client settings to setup higher timeouts - something like that way:

```scala
val kinesisClient = KinesisClientUtil
      .adjustKinesisClientBuilder(
        KinesisAsyncClient.builder.credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).region(awsRegion)
      )
      .httpClientBuilder(
        NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder
          .maxConcurrency(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
          .maxPendingConnectionAcquires(kinesisHttpMaxPendingConnectionAcquires)
          .maxHttp2Streams(kinesisHttpMaxConnections)
          .connectionAcquisitionTimeout(kinesisHttpConnectionAcquisitionTimeout)
          .connectionTimeout(kinesisHttpConnectionTimeout)
          .readTimeout(kinesisHttpReadTimeout)
          .http2Configuration(
            Http2Configuration.builder
              .initialWindowSize(10 * 1024 * 1024)
              .healthCheckPingPeriod(kinesisHttpHealthCheckPingPeriod)
              .maxStreams(kinesisHttpMaxConnections.longValue())
              .build
          )
          .protocol(Protocol.HTTP2)
      )
      .build()
```

I've set all the timeouts to 120 seconds and it did the trick.